# Can't access properties from a ngResource object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I fetch a database object with the following code:

```
// Lookup Project object from server
$scope.project = projectModel.get({}, {'id': session.projectId});
console.log('projectModel', $scope.project);
```

The output of the above is:

[image: projectModel]

I can't really interpret that output - i.e. what are the variables outside the {...}? In any case, trying to read e.g. `projectModel.name` just returns `undefined` - why?

Comment: `$scope.project.name` should be the way to read `projectModel's` name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projectModel.get({}, { 'id': session.projectId },
    function (successResponse) {
        // success callback
        console.log('successResponse:', successResponse);
    },
    function (errorResponse) {
        // failure callback
        console.log(errorResponse);
    }
);
```

try this. You will get the promise value in success response.

Answer (score 2):

You made an async call and the value you want is most likely not yet assigned when you tried to print to console. You could assign `$scope.project` this way

```
projectModel.get({'id': session.projectId}, 
    function (data) {
        $scope.project = data;
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this will most likely print out "undefined", right? Since the log statement executes before the callback does.

Answer (score 0):

projectModel is not the same as $scope.project, in $scope.project you get a resolved promise and when it is resolved, you can access name with: console.log('$scope.project.name');
Your resource - projectModel is propably a deffered object

You can read about promises here: [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Comment: Thanks! But I do see the data I want in the output above - how can I access it?

Comment: If $scope.project.name give you undefined, you can access it like this: projectModel.get({}, {...}).then(function (response) {$console.log(response, response.name); });

Comment: `.then()` is a `$q` method, right? But I don't think ngResource uses `$q`, does it?

Comment: I see on your screenshot, that it is a promise. Also, $resource is based on $http, and $http is based on $q, so it does :) If your resource is based on $resource or $http you can use also .success method as described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http